# Circular reference when building recursive string patterns

Tags: typescript

Very simple question here.

This creates a circular reference problem:

```
type OneOrMore<A extends string> = `${A}${OneOrMore<A> | ""}`

declare function u(str: OneOrMore<"a">): void;

u("a")
u("aa")
u("aaaaa")
u("aaaaaaaaaaaa")
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhGAnAsgeyRAPAQShAD2AjgBMBnKc4JASzgHMA%20KAXigAMASAbxwF9e8RKgzYcLAD5QARDP4cAUItIQAxgBsAhpigAzAK5w1wWmjhQDACmpIAXLATJ0mLDK0ymASgcA3NLSkANzK1u4yXophWh6R0TExEVFW7glpaRFAA)

Is there any way to achieve such a recursive string pattern in TypeScript?

Comment: Because you're using this type in a function, you can make it generic, and validate the type parameter, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR0Jnm). Does this address the question? If so, I could write up an answer, if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I indeed saw this solution somewhere but was hoping for something more "light". If this is the only solution, then please yes, post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to create these recursive string patterns, not yet at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to use this type in the context of a function, you may consider making the function generic instead, and then validating that generic type parameter, which might look something along the lines of

```
declare function u<S extends string>(str: OneOrMore<"a", S>): void;
```

The validation could then be done like this:

```
type OneOrMore<A extends string, S extends string, O = S> = S extends `${A}${infer Rest}` ? Rest extends "" ? O : OneOrMore<A, Rest, O> : never;
```

We first store the original string `S` in `O` for later. Then, we check if `S` starts with `A`. If it does, we check the rest of the string. If not, we return `never` (nothing is assignable to `never`, so you'll get an error if the string fails the test).

If the rest of the string is empty, that means we're done, so we'll return the original string (remember that `S` represents the rest of the string from the previous iteration). If it isn't empty, we still have to test it, making sure we pass the original string to the next iteration.

Example test cases:

```
u("a") // okay
u("aa") // okay
u("aaaaa") // okay
u("aaaaaaaaaaaa") // okay
u("aaaaaaaaaab") // error, has a b
u("baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") // error, has a b
u("abababab") // error, has lots of b's
u("") // error, does not have one or more a's
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhGAnAsgeyRAPAQShAD2AjgBMBnKc4JASzgHMAaKAZXyJIqpvudigBeNgD4hbDsTKUABgBIA3jgC+i+gDMISKACUI1ZTKgB+XfuCSulAETWTAgFywEydJlws91FjDFOEAG5aANwAUKGkEADGADYAhphQ6gCucFHAtGhwUMlY7IRS3NR0jCIAFMVO8IioGNjWcdYsrCIAlE4BaLSkYaHJZQ3WrX0DcY3D-Q1jY0MjU9ML07OTi4sARssDa6s7SxOj24dxG-u2rUA)